# Allocating 8 bytes of memory dynamically

Tags: c++

I want to create an integer array that can hold 8 bytes of data,
I have used this code

```
int n =50; 
long long *buffer = new long  long [n];
```

the size of **long long** is 8 bytes but

```
sizeof(buffer)
```

only gives **4 bytes** is it that the heap doesn't allow more than 4 bytes allocation? there is something that I have missed here but don't know what it is.

Comment: That's the size of the pointer, not the size of the allocated memory - there is no way of finding that out.

Comment: sizeof(buffer) vs sizeof(*buffer)

Comment: `sizeof` gives the size of the pointer, not of the memory allocated. In C++ most of the array problems go away if you use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Severin  sizeof(*buffer)  would be sizeof(long long)

Comment: ah I see, that's basic pointer stuff that I should have known thank you guys for clearing it up.

Comment: cost of allocated memory 8B is relatively high (far, far more than 8B) , suggest design in different way

Comment: @BoPersson I must use an array specifically because of supervisor other wise i would have used a vector or a list even.

Comment: `sizeof(long long) * 50` will give the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof (x)` gives the number of bytes consumed by `x`.   In your case `x` is the pointer to the allocation.   If the allocation succeeds, you know that it allocated the requested size (or possibly a little more).